# realtime process,but no work for tens of milliseconds

Tags: c++, linux, windows, linux-kernel

I'm send UDP packet from windows to linux(ubuntu 1804) with 100Mbps.
every 7ms send (32KB-128KB),but meet some problem.

when I run for a few minutes，the receiver can't deal realtime, and sometime the sender also can't send in 7ms.

windows process I used REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS,and at linux, I try to adjust nice or SCHED_DEADLINE or FIFO.

the sender and receiver both use about 10% CPU(My two machines are both 8 cores, and idle).Intranet bandwidth is 1Gbps。

read the log，I see the process sometimes no work for tens of milliseconds。Between two lines of logs there is no lock and sleep.
such as

```
EReadStatus rst           = self->worker_RetrieveUnit((id), (unit), (sa));
printf("==now= %s\n", FormatTime(steady_clock::now()).c_str());
```

at end of worker_RetrieveUnit,I write the systime，and outside I write the systime。
but sometimes the time difference for tens of milliseconds.

Can anyone explain?

such code run will crash

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
using namespace std;
void SetCpuWhich() {
    int cpu_num=sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF);
    std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<":cpu_num:"<<cpu_num<<std::endl;

    int cpu_which=1;
    cpu_set_t mask;
    CPU_ZERO(&mask);
    CPU_SET(cpu_which,&mask);
    if(sched_setaffinity(0,sizeof(mask),&mask)==-1) {
        std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<":sched_setaffinity false:cpu_which:"<<cpu_which<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    else {
        std::cout<<__FUNCTION__<<":sched_setaffinity true:cpu_which:"<<cpu_which<<std::endl;
    }
}
void adjustNice() {
    int incr = -20;
    int ret = nice(incr);
    if (!ret) {
       cout << "nice error" << endl;
    }
}


struct sched_attr {
    uint32_t size;              /* Size of this structure */
    uint32_t sched_policy;      /* Policy (SCHED_*) */
    uint64_t sched_flags;       /* Flags */
    int32_t sched_nice;         /* Nice value (SCHED_OTHER, SCHED_BATCH) */
    uint32_t sched_priority;    /* Static priority (SCHED_FIFO, SCHED_RR) */
    /* Remaining fields are for SCHED_DEADLINE */
    uint64_t sched_runtime;
    uint64_t sched_deadline;
    uint64_t sched_period;
};

int sched_setattr(pid_t pid, const struct sched_attr *attr, unsigned int flags)
{
   return syscall(__NR_sched_setattr, pid, attr, flags);
}


void setRtRun() {
    struct sched_attr attr;
    attr.size = sizeof(attr);
    attr.sched_policy = SCHED_DEADLINE;
    attr.sched_flags = 0;
    attr.sched_nice = 0;
    attr.sched_priority = 0;

    attr.sched_runtime = 5000000;
    attr.sched_period = 7000000;
    attr.sched_deadline = 7000000;

    pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);

    if (sched_setattr(tid, &attr, 0)) {
        cout << "error " << errno <<  endl;
        perror("sched_setattr()");
    }
}


void do_work(int64_t val) {
    (void)val;
}
int main() {
    // adjustNice();
    // SetCpuWhich();
    // setRtRun();
    int64_t sum = 0;
    while(true) {
        struct timeval start;
        gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
        cout << start.tv_sec << ":"<< start.tv_usec << " start send " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
            sum += i;
        }
        do_work(sum);
        struct timeval end;
        gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
        cout << end.tv_sec << ":"<< end.tv_usec << " end send " << endl;
        if ((end.tv_sec*1000000 + end.tv_usec - start.tv_sec*1000000 - start.tv_usec) > 10000) {
            assert(false);
            throw std::runtime_error{"send too slow!!"};
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code example? and providing the .log would also helping. Please consider to take a look at [example]

Comment: Windows nor linux are real time and even there are UDP cannot guaranty a time to transfert

Comment: As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].